# Pipe with printf command

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have made history command in C which stores and fetches commands to/from file. Now I am trying to run 'head' over it by piping. i.e history | head -3

For that I have first dup2() the stdout to write end of pipe. Then used printf to print history (which obv wont be displayed on screen). Now after that I have redirected stdin to read of that pipe and execvp() head command. It is displaying top 3 lines correctly. But It is still waiting for user input. I have to terminate by Ctrl C. Any idea why this is happening. Even I tried flushing everything into stdout after displaying history. Nothing seems to work.

```
pid=fork();
if(pid==0){
    if(...first time..){
        if(dup2(fd[1],1)<0){
              printf("Error in Dup!!");
        }
        printHistory();
        for(k = 0;k < totalfds; k++){
              close(fd[k]);
        }
        return;
    }
    if(...second time..){
        if(dup2(fd[0],0)<0){
            printf("Error in Dup!!");
            }
    }   
    ...
    execvp(subcomm[0],subcomm);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where's the code? Why is [tag:shell] listed?

Comment: Its a shell implementation in C. That's why. I guess code wont be required still I will edit it.

Comment: This probably has more to do with how `head` works than anything.  How does it expect its input to end?

Comment: Exactly how to show head that it has ended ?? Any idea??

Comment: Close the pipe?  That should send eof.

Comment: End your messages with a newline; it helps.  It may not be all that's necessary, but it is a start.  Also consider sending error messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: The usual problem with commands not terminating on EOF is that you've not closed enough file descriptors.  If the `head` command still has the write file descriptor for the pipe open, then it will try reading and will hang because the write end of the pipe is open — even though it is the `head` process that has it open and it won't write until the read returns. Also, your child that does `printHistory()` should probably `exit(0)` when it is done — not return.  If it returns, it will probably go back into the read loop.

Comment: I have closed the pipe after displaying history..Still the same issue...And yes messages are ending with new line while using printf in displaying history.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exit(0) did the trick !! Awesome..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual problem with commands not terminating on EOF is that you've not closed enough file descriptors. If the `head` command still has the write file descriptor for the pipe open, then it may try reading and will hang because the write end of the pipe is open — even though it is the `head` process that has it open and it won't write until the read returns.

Also, your child that does `printHistory()` should probably do `exit(0)` (or maybe `_exit(0)`) when it is done — not return. If it returns, it will probably go back into the read loop.  You should also ensure that you exit the process (with a non-zero status) if `execvp()` fails.  There's never a need to check the return status of `execvp()` or other members of the `exec*()` functions.  If they return, they failed; if they succeed, the original process is replaced by the new one, and the function never returns.

Also, as a general comment, end your messages with a newline; it helps ensure they appear in a timely fashion. Also consider sending error messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.